# Javascript - undefined function error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and java-script. for my code i keep getting that my functions aren't defined and i cant figure out why. ive tried moving the script to the head tag and after the call. ive tried changing the name of the function to a ensure it wasnt already being used. i think im missing something small and stupid.  any help will be appreciated

```
<html>

    <script type= "text/javascript" >

    var d = new Array(0,0,0,0,0);

    function aaa()
    {   alert( "hello" );
        for (var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        var da = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
        var di document.getElementById("d" + i);
        di.src = "pix/dice" + d + ".gif";
        }
    }

    function newGame(){
    }

    function click1()   {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <5; i++){
        if (d[i] == 1 ) total +=1;}
        var loco = document.getElementById("s1");
        loco.innerHTML = total;

        }

    </script>

    <h1>Yahtzee</h1>

    <div style = "text-align:center;">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d0">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d1">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d2">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d3">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d4">
    </div>
    <table border =2 align =center>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 1's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s1" onclick= "click1()" > </div>    </td>
            <td class = "c3" rowspan = "6"><button id = "roll;" onclick = "aaa()";>Roll</button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class = "c1"> 2's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s2"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 3's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s3"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 4's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s4"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 5's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s5"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 6's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s6"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 3 of a kind  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k3"> </div></td>
            <td class = "c3" rowspan = "8"><button id = "ng" onclick="newGame()"; >New Game </button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 4 of a kind </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k4"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Full House </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "fh"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Sm Straight  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ss"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Lg Straight  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ls"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Yahtzee </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "yah"> </div></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Chance </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "cha"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Total</td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "tot"> </div></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in your `aaa` function: `var di = document.getElementById("d" + i)`.  It's missing an equals sign.

Comment: And i prefer the array literal `[0,0,0,0]` instead of the constructor.

Comment: One of the most important parts of learning (and then later coding) javascript is to use the browser console. (`console.log` and `console.error`) Throughout your code these lines will help you debug. Also even if you do not use these, the browser will still throw errors and warnings when it encounters problems, along with the (more often then not) the exact line number on which the error occurred. You can open the console through developer tools in most modern browsers (ussual keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+i`). Learn to love the console, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was that you forget to add `=` after `di` in line

```
 var di document.getElementById("d" + i);
```

```js
var d = new Array(0,0,0,0,0);
  
  function aaa()
  { 
      var i = 0
      alert( "hello" );
   for(i; i<5; i++){
      var randomn = Math.random();
   var da = Math.floor(randomn*6) +1;
      var elid = "d" + i;
   var di = document.getElementById(elid);
   di.src = "pix/dice" + d + ".gif";
   }
  }
  
  function newGame(){
  }
  
  function click1() {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <5; i++){
   if (d[i] == 1 ){total +=1;}
   var loco = document.getElementById("s1");
   loco.innerHTML = total;
   }
   }
```

```html
<h1>Yahtzee</h1>
  
  <div style = "text-align:center;">
   <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d0">
   <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d1">
   <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d2">
   <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d3">
   <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d4">
  </div>
  <table border =2 align =center>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 1's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s1" onclick= "click1()" > </div>   </td>
    <td class = "c3" rowspan = "6"><button id = "roll;" onclick = "aaa();">Roll</button> </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class = "c1"> 2's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s2"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 3's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s3"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 4's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s4"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 5's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s5"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 6's </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s6"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 3 of a kind  </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k3"> </div>   </td>
    <td class = "c3" rowspan = "8"><button id = "ng" onclick="newGame()"; >New Game </button> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> 4 of a kind </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k4"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Full House </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "fh"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Sm Straight  </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ss"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Lg Straight  </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ls"> </div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Yahtzee </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "yah"> </div>   </td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Chance </td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "cha"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class = "c1"> Total</td>
    <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "tot"> </div>   </td>
   </tr>
  
  
  
  </table>
```

Comment: i spent so much time looking at it and i cant believe( but knew it ) was something so simple. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code has corrected your syntax error, and now the functions are being called (you can see the "hello" alert as desired).

```js
    var d = [0,0,0,0,0];

    function aaa()
    {   alert( "hello" );
        for (var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        var da = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
        var di = document.getElementById("d" + i);
        di.src = "pix/dice" + d + ".gif";
        }
    }

    function newGame(){
    }

    function click1()   {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <5; i++){
        if (d[i] == 1 ) total +=1;}
        var loco = document.getElementById("s1");
        loco.innerHTML = total;

        }
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    
    <h1>Yahtzee</h1>

    <div style = "text-align:center;">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d0">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d1">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d2">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d3">
        <img src = "pix/dice0.gif" id = "d4">
    </div>
    <table border =2 align =center>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 1's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s1" onclick= "click1()" > </div>    </td>
            <td class = "c3" rowspan = "6"><button id = "roll;" onclick = "aaa()";>Roll</button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class = "c1"> 2's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s2"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 3's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s3"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 4's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s4"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 5's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s5"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 6's </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "s6"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 3 of a kind  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k3"> </div></td>
            <td class = "c3" rowspan = "8"><button id = "ng" onclick="newGame()"; >New Game </button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> 4 of a kind </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "k4"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Full House </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "fh"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Sm Straight  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ss"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Lg Straight  </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "ls"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Yahtzee </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "yah"> </div></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Chance </td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "cha"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "c1"> Total</td>
            <td class = "c2"><div class = "scr" id = "tot"> </div></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```